# estoy desarrollando una app en Android studio y en un Activty Main, tengo 2 public void, que no funcionan correctamente

Tags: java, android-studio, postgresql

este void es para buscar el DNI en una base de datos y mostrarlos en el los TextView
usando una web service con una base de datos en posgresql

```
    public void buscarDni (){
        String dnipersonal = EditTextDni.getText().toString();
        if (dnipersonal.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText( this, "Ingrese DNI por favor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            EditTextDni.requestFocus();
        }else {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue( this);
            String url = WebService.RAIZ+ WebService.BuscarDni+ "?dni=" + EditTextDni.getText();
            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            TextViewNames.setText(jsonObject.getString("nombres"));

                            textViewApellidoP.setText(jsonObject.getString("apellido_paterno"));
                            textViewApellidoM.setText(jsonObject.getString("apellido_materno"));
                            textViewOficina.setText(jsonObject.getString("nombre"));

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dni Invalido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        }
    }
```

Este otro código dentro del mismo activity main, para guardar los datos buscados con el Void anterior y agregar otros datos

```
 public void RegistrarSolicitud(){
        String url11= WebService.RAIZ + WebService.GuardarSolicitud ;//+ "?=" ;
        String nombre = EditTextDni.getText().toString();

        /*if (nombre.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Escribir DNI !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Focus en jugar y abrir el Teclado
            EditTextDni.requestFocus();
        } else {*/
        //final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show( this, "guardando...","Espere" );

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url11,
                new Response.Listener<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // loading.dismiss();
                        mostrarDialogoBasico();
                        //limpiarcampos();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERRORrrrr", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map< String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

               String fecha_solicitud = textViewFecha_solicitud.getText().toString().trim();
                String dni_persona = EditTextDni.getText().toString().trim();
                String nombres_persona = TextViewNames.getText().toString().trim();
                String apellido_paterno = textViewApellidoP.getText().toString().trim(); //
                String apellido_materno = textViewApellidoM.getText().toString().trim();
                String oficina_persona = textViewOficina.getText().toString().trim();
                String text_fundamentacion = editTextfundamentacion.getText().toString().trim();
                String tipo_salida = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

                PapeletaSalida p = new PapeletaSalida ( fecha_solicitud, dni_persona,nombres_persona,apellido_paterno,
                        apellido_materno,oficina_persona,text_fundamentacion, tipo_salida);


                Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String,String>();  //Hashtable<>();
                //Map<String,String> params=new Hashtable<>(); HashMap

                params.put("fecha_solicitud", p.getFechaPapeleta() );
                params.put("dni_persona", p.getDni_persona());
                params.put("nombres_persona", p.getNombres_persona());
                params.put("apellido_paterno", p.getApellido_paterno());
                params.put("apellido_materno", p.getApellido_materno());
                params.put("oficina_persona", p.getOficina_persona());
                params.put("text_fundamentacion", p.getText_fundamentacion());
                params.put("tipo_salida", p.getTipo_salida());
                //params.put("tipo_salida", p.getTipo_salida());
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```

cuando hago click en el button para buscar los datos del DNI funciona, pero no me guarda nada cuando sigo en el button para guardar los otros datos

pero si solo registro los datos en las cajas si guarda

no se como seguir desde este punto, pido que alguien me pueda apoyar

Comment: ¿Dónde estás llamando a `RegistrarSolicitud()`?

Comment: en el mismo activity main, en un button que también esta en el activity main